# Is it considered a good practice by any stretch to use a mix of CMS and Laravel in a web app?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, laravel

I was wondering if its okay to use a CMS like wordpress to develop and manage static pages of a website (e.g landing pages) while using a framework like laravel strictly for user portal.

Has anyone used this combo before? 
If so, what's your experience doing so?
If not, what do you think about this approach.

The goal is to save time and perhaps give room for blogging activities later.

Comment: better use your laravel in subfolder and keep wordpress in parent folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the specifics, but this approach seems to be fairly common. Plenty of companies use Wordpress on a subdomain like `blog.website.com` while having the main app on `website.com`. The opposite seems less common, but is also done.

It may get messy depending on how closely URLs need to be integrated. If you can put one on a subdomain, there should be no problems. If it must live in its own subdirectory, that is probably fine as well. If the page URLs need to be woven in together, that will get complicated.

The company I work for currently does the subdomain approach. A CMS runs our main website (landing page, blog, and customer info) and we have numerous custom apps which run on subdomains.

A CMS runs `calgaryparking.com` and we have apps on various subdomains.